# Databricks error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)[Ljava/lang/Object;

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks, nosuchmethoderror

I am trying to run some sample code from this link: https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/5537430417240233/312903576646278/3506802399907740/latest.html

I am running it in a databricks notebook on a cluster with runtime 6.3 (includes Apache Spark 2.4.4, Scala 2.11) 
I initially create a dataframe using

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
    ("one", 2.0),
    ("two", 1.5),
    ("three", 8.0)
  ).toDF("id", "val")
```

and then I try to get a list of strings by running
`df.select("id").map(_.getString(0)).collect.toList`

and i get the error below

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)[Ljava/lang/Object;

t line3700fe51392b4abe9744f6b3a059dbfa46.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(command-1275538363433250:2)
    at line3700fe51392b4abe9744f6b3a059dbfa46.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(command-1275538363433250:53)
    at line3700fe51392b4abe9744f6b3a059dbfa46.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(command-1275538363433250:55)
    at line3700fe51392b4abe9744f6b3a059dbfa46.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(command-1275538363433250:57)
    at line3700fe51392b4abe9744f6b3a059dbfa46.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(command-1275538363433250:59)
    at line3700fe51392b4abe9744f6b3a059dbfa46.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.(command-1275538363433250:61)
    at line3700fe51392b4abe9744f6b3a059dbfa46.$read$$iw$$iw.(command-1275538363433250:63)
    at line3700fe51392b4abe9744f6b3a059dbfa46.$read$$iw.(command-1275538363433250:65)
    at line3700fe51392b4abe9744f6b3a059dbfa46.$read.(command-1275538363433250:67)
    at line3700fe51392b4abe9744f6b3a059dbfa46.$read$.(command-1275538363433250:71)
    at line3700fe51392b4abe9744f6b3a059dbfa46.$read$.(command-1275538363433250)
    at line3700fe51392b4abe9744f6b3a059dbfa46.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(:7)
    at line3700fe51392b4abe9744f6b3a059dbfa46.$eval$.$print(:6)
    at line3700fe51392b4abe9744f6b3a059dbfa46.$eval.$print()
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:793)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1054)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:645)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:644)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:644)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:576)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:572)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverILoop.execute(DriverILoop.scala:215)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply$mcV$sp(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExitInternal$.trapExit(DriverLocal.scala:699)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExit$.apply(DriverLocal.scala:652)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.repl(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$9.apply(DriverLocal.scala:385)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$9.apply(DriverLocal.scala:362)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:251)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:246)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:49)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:288)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:49)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:362)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:639)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:485)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:597)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:390)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:337)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:219)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I get the same error when running 
`df.select("id").collect().map(_(0)).toList`

but not when running 
`df.select("id").rdd.map(_(0)).collect.toList`

The command above that runs successfully returns a List[Any], but I need a List[String]

Can someone please advise? I suspect it's a sparkscala version mismatch, but I can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75947449/run-a-scala-code-jar-appear-nosuchmethoderrorscala-predef-refarrayops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)[Ljava/lang/Object;
```

often arises if you mix different scala versions. Do you have any dependencies loaded for scala 2.12?

**EDIT**: I just tested your code in databricks with the same runtime, worked just fine....

Comment: Just tested it too on Databricks Community. Can confirm works fine.

Comment: Thank you Raphael. I had some libraries installed on my cluster that probably used Scala 2.12. I've uninstalled them and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

In **`.map`** convert to string using **`.toString`** then the result would be **`List[String]`**

**`Example:`**

```
df.select("id").collect().map(x => x(0).toString).toList
List[String] = List(one, two, three)
```

Comment: Thank you Shu. Unfortunately this results in the same error. I have also tried this ```df.select("id").collect().map(_(0)).toList``` and this ```df.select("id").collect().map(each => (each.getAs[String]("id"))).toList``` which both result in the same error.